# Having problems with dpkg was interrupted, broken packages and lock the administration directory

Tags: dpkg

I'm having problems:

- dpkg was interrupted
- broken packages
- Unable to lock the administration directory

And I think they are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your computer and follow above.

to update your package list.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to clean up any partial packages.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clean up the apt cache.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

clean up any unneeded dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Resolve dependencies of broken packages

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

fix dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

Correct dpkg

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Run all this list more than once to fix the problem, if it was not resolved.

Comment: haha.. Nice u found Your own answer :)

Comment: @minigeek It was not accepted yet because it didn't fix the problem yet. I want to build a list of lot of commands to fix this kind of problem that are usually connected and we have to search on many foruns.

Comment: just try solution i  wrote...i found this solution after lots of efforts ..before that i used to reinstall ubuntu lol.

Comment: Yeah. I did it once haha. reinstalling sucks. I will try it, I already upvoted your answer. I will try it.

Comment: yeah sure ..thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove <package name>
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo apt-get update
```

if still  problem exists or sudo apt-get install -f doesnt fix this problem then do this :
remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!